# Passing a CSV url when instantiating a class in the Django Framework

Tags: python, django

I'm using the Django Python framework to retrieve data from a CSV.

The code works, but I am trying to make the code reusable and I haven't been able to accomplish that because I can't find a way to pass the url to the csv from an instance.

The code of the view is as follows:

```
class ThreeLinerCSV(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):

        with open('csvpathhere.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            csv1 = list(reader)

            header = list(csv1[0].keys())

            #Headers
            headerData0 = header[0]
            headerDataTxt0 = str(headerData0)
            headerData1 = header[1]
            headerDataTxt1 = str(headerData1)
            headerData2 = header[2]
            headerDataTxt2 = str(headerData2)
            headerData3 = header[3]
            headerDataTxt3 = str(headerData3)

            #Data arrays
            Date = reversed([i[headerDataTxt0] for i in csv1])
            DataValue1  = reversed([i[headerDataTxt1] for i in csv1])
            DataValue2  = reversed([i[headerDataTxt2] for i in csv1])
            DataValue3 = reversed([i[headerDataTxt3] for i in csv1])

            #Data to send to views
            data = {
            "labels": Date,
            "dataAxis1": DataValue1,    
            "dataAxis2": DataValue2,
            "dataAxis3": DataValue3,
            "headerData1": headerData1,
            "headerData2": headerData2,
            "headerData3": headerData3,


            }

            return Response(data)


#I call the class here
OISLIBOR = ThreeLinerCSV()
```

Then, the **urls.py** has this:

```
    url(r'^api/OISLIBOR/data/$', OISLIBOR.as_view()),
```

I need to find a way to get the "csvpathhere.csv" out of the class and be able to input it from the instance. Any idea of how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by input from instance?

Comment: For example, to be able to pass the csv location in OISLIBOR = ThreeLinerCSV(LOCATIONHERE).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly, you could pass the target CSV name as a GET query string parameter.

You would have to change one line in your view:

```
with open(request.GET.get('target_name'), newline='') as csvfile:
```

And the call your endpoint like this

```
http: ... api/OISLIBOR/data/?target_name=here.goes.the.target.url
```

Comment: That did not seem to work. Can't get the "?target_name=here.goes.the.target.url" to function. I just get get no data.

Comment: If you do `print(request.GET)` inside your `get` method, is there any data in `request.GET` ? It should show all the query string parameters (the part after the `?` in the url).